# Reactive Spring Mono and doOnNext

Tags: spring, junit4, reactive

I use spring-boot-starter-webflux, reactor-test and spring-boot-starter-test 2.0.0.M7 in my project. In my `RepositoryInMemory.class` has a `List<String>` where you can add String values by `saveName(Mono<String> name)` method. You can also ask all the values that are added to the list by `getAllNames()` method. Problem is that how to test `RepositoryInMemory.class`? I have `RepositoryInMemoryTest.class` but seems like that it does not work because `List<String>` returns always 0. I know that the problem is `doOnNext` method in `RepositoryInMemory.class` but I don't know why and how to solve it. Does anyone know that how I should create a valid Junit test case?

**RepositoryInMemory** class

```
package com.example

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Repository
public class RepositoryInMemory {

    private final List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();

    public Flux<String> getAllNames() {
        return Flux.fromIterable(names);
    }

    public Mono<Void> saveName(Mono<String> name) {
        return name.doOnNext(report -> names.add(report)).then();
    }
}
```

**RepositoryInMemoryTest** class

```
package com.example

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class RepositoryInMemoryTest {

    @Autowired
    private RepositoryInMemory repository;

    @Test
    public void addDataToList_ShouldReturnOne() {
        Mono<String> name = Mono.just("Example Name");
        repository.saveName(name);
        int count = Math.toIntExact(repository.getAllNames().count().block());
        assertEquals(1, count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for clarification for the future readers, please use `subscribe()` instead of `block()`. Because `block()` will actually block the thread until the next signal is received, which is against the asynchronous concept.

Use `block()` if you really want to switch back to synchronous flow.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer my own question because I found the solution. The only thing what you have to do is change this line `repository.saveName(name);` to this `repository.saveName(name).block();`. It's activate `doOnNext` method.

Comment: I think also `subscribe()` would do the job

Comment: block() will block.. subscribe() or subscribeWith() will not block..